# Like button not working because of a javascript hangup

Tags: javascript, button, iframe, facebook-like

I have a problem, i am using the iframe version of the Like button, but i does not seem to work. When i press like, it shows the count timer, but it does not show up on my facebook under my interests.

Here is a link to the debugger: http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.softib.lv%252Flv%252Fkrustvardu-miklas%252F

Anything else i should provide?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you need open graph meta tags in the head of your page. But, I didn't see the like button on your page. It would help if we could see and test it.